# C++: Casting de una clase padre a un hija?

Tags: c++

tengo dos clases `lib_array_list` que hereda de `lib_object`:

```
class lib_array_list : public lib_object
{
    size_t len;
    size_t sizememory;
    lib_object** objs;//es un array que cada tipo es de lib_object
    std::string name;

    public:


    lib_array_list():len{0},sizememory{4}, objs{new lib_object*[4]}
    {
         name = "noname";
    }

    lib_array_list(std::string name)
    :name{name},len{0},sizememory{4}, objs{new lib_object*[4]}
    {
    }

    std::string get_array_list_name(){
         return name;
    }

    lib_object& get_array_list_by_name(std::string name){
         return get(0);
    }

    lib_object& get(size_t pos){

        return *(objs[pos]);
    }
```

Mi clase lib_object:

```
class lib_object{


public:

lib_object()
{

}
virtual ~lib_object()
{
}
virtual std::string to_string() const
{
     return "x";
}
virtual bool operator ==(const lib_object& obj) const
{
     return false;
}
virtual std::string get_class_name()const
{
     return "lib_object";
}

};
```

Mi clase array_list puede almacenar objectos del mismo tipo, osea arraylists de arralists y en mi clase lib_array_list tengo una funcion `get_array_list_by_name` que de momento me retorna un `lib_object&`de la primera posicion y lo que necesito es hacer un casting a `lib_array_list` para poder operar sobre la misma, pero tengo error en ejecucion: **Aborted (core dumped)** mi casting lo estoy haciendo asi:

```
lib_array_list r = (lib_array_list&)r.get_array_list_by_name("students");
```

Como debo castear de `lib_object` a `lib_array_list` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los cast a clases hijas deben hacerse con dynamic_cast la explicación está en el item 5 de la explicación de dynamic_cast reference("https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast"), también es posible hacer downcast usando static_cast pero este no hace checkeo de tipos en tiempo de ejecución. (cast inseguro).

Un ejemplo de el uso sería :
Sea A una clase base y B una derivada de A

```
 A * pB = new B();
 B * pB2 = dynamic_cast<B*>(pB);
```

En tu caso un simple será suficiente.

```
lib_array_list & ref = dynamic_cast<lib_array_list&>(r.get_array_list_by_name("students"));
```

Saludos.

Comment: "*Los cast a clases hijas deben hacerse con `dynamic_cast`*", esto no es cierto; las conversiones en cualquier dirección del árbol de herencia pueden hacerse con cualquier operación de conversión que sea adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

[El error que recibes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcado_de_memoria) suele tener que ver con manejo de memoria no con problemas de conversión en el árbol de herencia.

Sin ver cómo rellenas de datos de tu `lib_array_list` y cómo lo usas y vacías es difícil hacer conjeturas, lo habitual para ese tipo de error suele ser una doble liberación de memoria.

Por otro lado, estás haciendo las cosas mal, estás **copiando** una clase base en una derivada:

```
//             v <--- Instancia
lib_array_list r = (lib_array_list&)r.get_array_list_by_name("students");
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Referencia
```

Por lo que he podido ver, la clase `lib_array_list` no dispone de constructores de copia para la clase `lib_object` así que a priori, no sabrá cómo hacer esa copia. Seguramente lo que querías era una referencia:

```
lib_array_list &r = (lib_array_list&)r.get_array_list_by_name("students");
```

Es posible que al hacer las copias, estés invocando los destructores de algunos objetos temporales y esto te provoque el error de memoria.

Para acabar, evita las conversiones de datos de tipo C (`(tipo)dato`) y usa las de C++ (`xxxxxx_cast<tipo>(dato)`); las de C++ son más seguras.

Comment: 1.- Que pasa si el resultado de esa funcion es 'null' osea no existe la tabla 'students', por definicion mi funcion como retorna una referencia no puedo retornar null,  que deberia hacer en este caso?

Comment: 2.- Si mi funcion get_array_list_by_name retornara un puntero, como deberia retornar una referencia a ese puntero?

Comment: PD: Te agradezco la ayuda

Comment: 1) Al des-referenciar un puntero nulo en la función `lib_array_list::get` el programa fallará aún antes de asignar la referencia. 2) No necesitas retornar referencia al puntero porque el puntero ya apunta al dato, pero si lo necesitases sería `puntero *&`.

Comment: Perfecto gracias !